# use setInterval to achieve parameter add 10 every 5seconds but the result sequence is very strange

Tags: vue.js, setinterval

I use `setInterval` to achieve  parameter mytime add `10` every 5seconds.

For example, I expect to get a result list like `1` `11`  `21` `31` `41`...

But the real result sequence is `1` `11` `31` `71` `151` `311`...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=" utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app-6">
    {{ aaa() }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  var app6 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-6',
    data: {
      mytime: 1
    },
    methods: {
      aaa: function() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.bbb()
        }, 5000);
        return this.mytime;
      },
      bbb: function() {
        this.mytime = this.mytime + 10;
      },
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time it re-renders, it calls `aaa()` again. And every time this function is called, it sets a new timer.

Everytime a timer is set, it will add multiple times:

- at first it adds `10` (because there's only one timer), but this first adding triggers `aaa()` again, which creates an additional timer
- so when another 5s pass, there are two timers now, which add `10` each, this going from `11` to  `31` straight. But this change also triggers `aaa()` which also creates new timers, and this goes on...

**Solution:** My suggestion is you add `{{ mytime }}` to the templated and trigger one `setInterval()` only at the `created()` lifecycle hook.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=" utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app-6">
    {{ mytime }}
  </div>
  <script>
    var app6 = new Vue({
      el: '#app-6',
      data: {
        mytime: 1
      },
      created() {
          setInterval(() => {
            this.bbb()
          }, 5000);
      },
      methods: {
        bbb: function() {
          this.mytime = this.mytime + 10;
        },
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, thank u again, I am a new user of stackoverflow and I didnot know the rules. Now I clicked 'accept'. Anything else I should do?

Comment: could u please tell me the michanism of re-rending, or give me some document(url),thank u again

Comment: Oh, no, don't worry. There was no problem. Nothing you need to do :) By the way, welcome. If you are going to stay with us, I suggest you change your username to be more personal, but that's not an obligation, do as you like.

Comment: Here's what I suggest you read: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods The whole guide is good, and you can read parts of it as you go. Keep it up.